Input Action, Unity
Created a new action, and returned an error:Assets\PlayerInputActions.cs(286,14): error CS0111: Type 'PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions' already defines a member called 'OnMove' with the same parameter types

please help me, I will be very grateful

Could you provide some more details about your code and what you think went wrong?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
